# linux - is there a more advanced version of top?

Tags: linux, top

Is there any type of super-top command that will show the results through time?  With regular top, it will tell me for an instant what processes are using what, but is there anything that will show data for now, 1 minute ago, 2 minute ago etc?

Comment: Can you please specify whether you want to track individual processes, all processes at all times or just the over all resource use?

Answer (score 9):

There are several ones

```
htop
atop
nmon
```

Also Conky, which is highly configurable if you are running X based GUI, and procexp, which is also gui.

Depending on your specifc usage, you can use top in scripts. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184386/top-command-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 1):

You want something more like nagios/cacti that can show data over time.
nagios for raw numbers and cacti for graphs.

Comment: Hi Matthew, welcome to Super User! can you expand on this a bit? Maybe provide some screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

atop is doing a really great job and you can also use it to record the data for later analysis.
nmon can also save data for later analysis.

on big advantage of atop is, that it also shows process that were starting AND ending within the refresh period (it show these process in "< >" ).